# 'Request invitation' doesn't give any feedback of successfully sending

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I filled the "Request an Invitation" form:

> [image]

But after submitting, I just got bumped back to the "check your profiles" page without being told whether it worked or not.

If it does work, I may have sent several requests...

Comment: Can't reproduce, getting [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vhce8.png) after submitting. Check your browser's Console to see if you get any client side errors.

Comment: I'm not getting any output in the console before or after submitting

Comment: So a dev would have to look into this and see if your requests have been sent.

Comment: @user759 Send me an email at jon@stackoverflow.com with your information. I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Jon got you set. I'm going to go ahead and mark this completed.